# How to convert song duration (String) to time where duration is more than 24 hours

Tags: vb.net, linq, datetime

The song duration which I'm reading from excel will exist in the range between "000:00:00" to "999:59:59".
When I try to parse the string to DataTime, if the hours are less than 24 it is working. But for hours greater than 23 it is throwing error like 'incorrect format'.

How can we parse the duration string to time, so that I can make sure the time is greater than 0 sec and less than 999 hours.

Comment: You need a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: Instead of a `DateTime`, which represents a fixed point in time (i.e `12.11.2020 16:14`), you need to convert it to a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0), which represents an arbitrarily long amount of time, using [`TimeSpan.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=net-5.0)

Comment: [TimeSpan.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse?view=net-5.0) is your friend. If the string could be parsed you can easy check with `TimeSpan.TotalHours <= 999`

Comment: We're talking about songs. Do you _really_ have any songs that run longer than 24 hours?

Comment: My input is "024:26:35", which is greater than 23 hours
I tried using TimeSpan.Parse and TimeSpan.TryParse.
TimeSpan.TryParse - returning 00:00:00
TimeSpan.Parse - Throwing error "The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits."

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn
I don't think so. But in the requirements we received, have this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan as follows.

Split the string by the colon. Then create a new TimeSpan by converting each portion of the string to an Integer.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Dim spanString = "024:26:35" 'produces 1.00:26:35 or 1 day, no hours, 26 minutes, 35 seconds
    Dim spanString = "999:59:59" 'produces 41.15:59:59 or 41 days, 15 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds
    Dim splits = spanString.Split(":"c)
    Dim ts As New TimeSpan(CInt(splits(0)), CInt(splits(1)), CInt(splits(2)))
    Debug.Print(ts.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`.

Note: The parsed string must conform to the [expected format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse). This means that the hours component ("999" in the example) is invalid as it must not exceed 23 (or 24 is the subsequent components are all "0").

So "23:59:59" is valid but "24:00:01" is not. So we need to pre-parse the string to obtain a number of days (and remainder hours) if the TOTAL time component exceeds 24 hours.

```
Dim SongLengthString As String = "999:59:59"
Dim SongLengthArray As String() = SongLengthString.Split(":"c)
If CInt(SongLengthArray(0)) > 23 AndAlso (SongLengthArray(1) <> "00" OrElse SongLengthArray(2) <> "00") Then SongLengthString = String.Join(":", CInt(SongLengthArray(0)) \ 24, CInt(SongLengthArray(0)) Mod 24, SongLengthArray(1), SongLengthArray(2))
Dim SongLength As TimeSpan
If Not TimeSpan.TryParse(SongLengthString, SongLength) Then MessageBox.Show("Song Length is invalid.")
```

(I'm sure you can do better than my rubbish pre-parsing line!)

This yields the expected maximum `SongLength` of 41.15:59:59. (I think only Neil Young has songs longer than this!) You can then validate the result against your specification.